# Deleted PHP session still exists in second ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, session

On page load I am doing an ajax request and deleting PHP Sessions when certain condition occurs. Here is it:

```
function load_page(){
console.log("page load function")
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/page_load.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "rand="+Math.random()*10000,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
       load_content(window.location.hash);
    }
});
```

}

Here is the `page_load.php`:

```
session_start();
require_once("../lib/connect.php");
require_once("../lib/users.php");
$user=new user();
if(isset($_SESSION['igames_user']))
{
    if(!$user->check_logged_in($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        print_r($_SESSION);
    }

}
```

It returns `Array()`, which means session is clear. 
In `load_content()` function I am doing another ajax request:

```
function load_content(hash){
hash=hash.replace("#","");
$("#wrapper").fadeOut(function(){
    var that=$(this);
    that.html('');
    that.addClass("loader");
    that.addClass("loading_center");
    that.fadeIn(function(){
        var data=hash
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/get_page.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                that.fadeOut(function(){
                    that.html(html);
                    that.removeClass("loader");
                    that.removeClass("loading_center");
                    that.fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

}

get_page.php only does this:

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

This does not return an empty array as expected.
What is the issue? Thanks for help.

Comment: try `unset($_SESSION['igames_user']);` as well.

Comment: can you paste your another function code as well ?

Comment: @GBD I have edited my question and added the second function as well

Comment: maybe try http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php#107089 and make sure you're not actually recreating the session somewhere along the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem by not calling the first ajax request and by checking condition and deleting sessions in the `get_page.php` file. Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, since you are doing an 'asynchronous' call, that the second js function is executed before the session is reset.

Comment: I have already tried using timeout and onComplete handler. No use. But after several refreshes(count varies every time) sessions are cleared.